# Multilangual spellchecking in Android

Tags: keyboard, spell-check

I have a ZTE Axon with Android 7. Sometimes I write German texts and other times I write English text.

With English as system language the spellchecking is set to English and it considers German text I write to be wrong. Is there a way to switch to bilingual spellchecking?